# Angular Unit Test should create FAILED TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'preferences')

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular-unit-test

I am trying to create cover all the line (Jasmine / Karma) but I am getting the error as **Cannot read property 'preferences' of undefined**

Here is my code for component code.

```
    export class PreferComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() updatePreferences = new EventEmitter<any>();
  @ViewChild('settingModal', { static: true }) settingModal: any;
  private data: any;
  preferences = [];
  maxCols: number;
  selectedPref: number;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.preferences = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.data.preferences));
    this.maxCols = this.data.maxCols;
    this.selectedPref = this.data.selectedPref;
    this.checkPreferences();
  }

  setPreferences(col, val) {
    if (val) {
      col.isPreferredColumn = true;
      this.selectedPref++;
    } else {
      col.isPreferredColumn = false;
      this.selectedPref--;
    }
    this.checkPreferences();
  }
}
```

Here is the below code for spec which I tried:

```
   fdescribe('PreferComponent ', () => {
  let component: PreferComponent ;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<PreferComponent >;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [PreferencesComponent],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]

    })
      .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(PreferComponent );
    fixture.detectChanges();

    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    const data1 = {
      preferences: [1, 2, 4],
      "maxCols": 5,
      "selectedPref": 7
    };
    component.preferences = data1.preferences;
    component.maxCols = data1.maxCols;
    component.selectedPref = data1.selectedPref;
    expect(component.preferences).toEqual([1, 2, 4]);

    component.ngOnInit();
  });
});
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `ngOnInit` method, you're assigning `this.preferences` with a value obtained from `this.data`.

Therefore, in the `beforeEach` function, you should make the following change:

*Instead of...*

```
component.preferences = data1.preferences;
```

*...write this:*

```
@ts-ignore
component.data = data1;
```

> Further you should move `expect(component.preferences).toEqual([1, 2, 4]);` after `component.ngOnInit();` since this checks if `ngOnInit` did what you expected it to do.

Comment: tried but no luck. data is private variable so i used it => component['data'] = data1;
    component.preferences = data1.preferences;

Comment: Then you should first inject `data` to the component in a regular way, somehow it needs to get a value if you're using it in `ngOnInit`. Another option would be to use `@ts-ignore` that allows you to assign data to a private class member.

Comment: I inject 'data' variable in regular but issue persist